# Required option if one option is set to true

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm building a jQuery plugin and I want to implement a function which should only run, if an option is set to `true`. This option wille be `false` by default.

If a user wants to use the functionality, an other option should be required, because the function needs an element of the page which should be passed into the required option.

How can I achieve this?

#### Edit

I'm still building up the main structure of the plugin, so no actual action is currently defined, but here's the structure of the plugin.

```
/**
 * Parallax Plugin API
 * @type {function}
 */
(function( $, window, document, undefined ) {

  /**
   * Parallax prototype
   * defines the functionality of the plugin
   * @type {Object}
   */
  var Parallax = {

    /**
     * Initialize the parallax effect
     * @param  {string || object}   options [options passed]
     * @param  {object}             element [$('.element').parallax( options )]
     */
    init: function( options, element ) {
      var self = this;
      self.element = element;
      self.$element = $( element );

      /**
       * Define self.options by overwriting the default options by the passed ones
       * @type {object}
       */
      self.options = $.extend( {}, $.fn.parallax.options, options );

      /**
       * Call the cycle function to navigate through the API
       */
      self.cycle();
    },

    /**
     * Cycle through the API
     */
    cycle: function() {
      var self = this;

      /**
       * Listen for scroll variable changes
       * Call the refresh function, if variable has changed
       */
      events.on( 'scrollChanged', self.refresh() );
    },

    /**
     * Refresh the animation
     */
    refresh: function() {
      var self = this;

    }
  };

  /**
   * Actual plugin function which is called by .parallax()
   * @param  {string || object} options [options passed]
   * @return {object}                   [return jQuery object to allow chaining]
   */
  $.fn.parallax = function( options ) {
    return this.each(function() {
      var parallax = Object.create( Parallax );
      parallax.init( options, this );
    });
  };

  /**
   * Set the default options
   * @type {Object}
   */
  $.fn.parallax.options = {
    direction: 'up',
    initOffset: '100%',
    speed: relative,
    relativeTo: $('.element')
  };
})( jQuery, window, document );
```

As you see, there's a `relativeTo` function. The reason is that I have built a functionality to move the parallaxing element at a calculated speed, so that it's centered in the user's viewport at the exact same time as the `relativeTo`-element is centered in the viewport.

If the `speed` option is set to `relative` the user should have to pass an element: `relativeTo`, if another value (`fast`, `slow`) is set to the `speed` option, the `relativeTo` is not needed.

Comment: What have you tried, and what does your plugin look like now

Comment: _How can I achieve this?_ What have you achieved so far? Where is your code that you have tried?

Comment: @adeneo Done! Hope, that you can help me. Btw, if you see anithing in the structure which isn't good, let me know, because I'm new to the plugin development.

Comment: Maybe something like -> https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/9eh2thrb/

Comment: Yeah, but if the option is required, I need to give the user a feedback if he forgets to set it.

Comment: @adeneo I know the TypeError, which should be thrown if there is a type error, but is there also an OptionsError which I could throw to tell the user, that there is a reuired option missing?